# Fatal error: class not found, but is loaded

Tags: php

I'm trying to run my script on a live server, but it is staging.

Locally, everything is fine (OS X), remotely, CentOS/Nginx, I'm having a fatal issue.. the script says that my custom database class cannot be found.

Looking at what's loaded, using `get_declared_classes()`, I can definitely see my custom database class, which is being loaded before the script/class that calls it.

It's being loaded through my autoloader:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
if (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'library' . DS . 'intranet' .DS . 'classes' . DS .strtolower($className) . '.php')){
    require_once(ROOT . DS . 'library' . DS . 'intranet' .DS . 'classes' . DS .strtolower($className) . '.php');
} else if (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS . 'controller' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php')) {
    require_once(ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS . 'controller' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php');
} else if (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS . 'model' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php')) {
    require_once(ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS . 'model' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php');
} else if (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS . 'view' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php')) {
    require_once(ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS . 'view' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php');
} else {
    throw new Exception("Class: $className not autoloaded!");
}
});
```

No exception is being thrown.

```
Array ( [128] => Router 
        [129] => debug 
        [130] => database 
        [131] => SessionManager 
        [132] => security 
) 

Fatal error: Class 'database' not found in 
/home/nginx/domains/ckrisc/public/library/intranet/classes/sessionmanager.php 
on line 76
```

Bootstrapping and file inclusion are as follows:

```
require_once (ROOT . DS . 'config'  . DS . 'config.php'                         );
require_once (ROOT . DS . 'config'  . DS . 'directories.config.php'             );
require_once (library . DS . 'setup.php'        );
require_once (library . DS . 'Autoloader.php'   );
require_once (library . DS . 'Router.php'       );
require_once (library . DS . 'init.php'         );
```

in this case, the class `database` is being called from the sessionmanager, which is called in  `init.php`.

The script is failing here:

```
$sessionId = database::getInstance()->real_escape_string($sessionId);
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Comment: call `get_declared_classes()` right before the exception. check backtrace

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, I did, and it has been loaded.

Comment: Is it literally in the preceding line to the exception?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, yep, I placed it just before the database class is called. I even placed it afterwards and it's still there.

Comment: how do you mean after, you said it throws an exception...

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception, it just fatals.

Comment: Ok, apparently it now isn't loaded just before the exception, but it is loaded before the session class is called. It's not showing as any classes being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that APC 3.1.13 was causing some problems

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are calling the class before the autoload function is declared.

Comment: Wouldn't the same happen in my development environment? The autoloader is called straight after the config and error reporting.

Comment: I mentioned the possibility because it seems the **database** is one of those classes that have to be called before any other process.

Comment: Yes, it's the third loaded class, see the array in my post.

Comment: Which means the class is not getting loaded. Exception might not been working, among other possibilities.

Comment: Which brings me to why it's not being loaded; it's not hitting the exception at all.